# Cannot connect with 3g modem during Arch installation

Tags: arch-linux, modem

I was trying to install Arch Linux with 3g modem. I had previously downloaded `usb_modswitch` and `wvdial` and their dependencies. I booted Arch and installed them. Then I copied my Ubuntu's `/etc/wvdial.conf` to Arch.

Then I connect with `wvdial` and it says connected,; modem indicator also says connected. But it is actually not! `ping www.google.com` says unknown host! The modem is HUAWEI E1550 (from a provider in Bangladesh).

Comment: What does `ifconfig` say? Does the network interface have a public IP after you connected with wvdial?

Comment: Abandoned: voting to close...

Answer (score 0):

have you checked `/etc/resolv.conf`? if that file is empty, try adding nameserver like this,

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: I didn't try it. will give a shot some moment later.

Comment: It didn't work!

Comment: Maybe `/etc/ppp/resolv.conf`? Also, don't forget to reconnect upon these changes.